# How to fix Bluetooth related errors on boot

Tags: 14.04, boot, bluetooth

When I boot my laptop, I see on the screen the following messages:

```
[    5.307568] Bluetooth: Error in firmware loading err = -110,len = 448, size = 4096
[    5.307601] Bluetooth: Loading patch file failed
[    5.307624] ath3k: probe of 3-5:1.0 failed with error -110
```

All these messages seems to be Bluetooth related.

How can I fix these errors? Is there any workaround for them? If not, how can I prevent showing them on the screen when booting the machine?

I don't even use Bluetooth, so removing the packages that produce this error would be fine.

I'm using Ubuntu [14.04](/questions/tagged/14.04).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue you are facing is due to a bug in older versions of the Linux kernel < 3.15.

The bug report can be found [here](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=73981). To solve the problem, enter the following commands:

> ```
> cd /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/drivers/bluetooth/
> cp ath3k.ko ath3k.ko.orig
> cp btusb.ko btusb.ko.orig
>
> sed -e 's/\xf3\x0c\x05\x30/\xf3\x0c\x05\xe0/g' ath3k.ko > at.ko
> sed -e 's/\xf3\x0c\x05\x30/\xf3\x0c\x05\xe0/g' btusb.ko > bt.ko
> mv at.ko ath3k.ko
> mv bt.ko btusb.ko
> rmmod ath3k
> rmmod btusb
> modprobe btusb
> modprobe ath3k
> ```

The original solution can be found [here](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1433352#p1433352) and is valid for Kernel Version 3.15.3-1-ARCH. I have modified the commands above to work with the user's kernel version using `uname -r`.

Alternatively, you can disable the bluetooth drivers by blacklisting them.

```
gksu gedit /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

Add the following lines to this file -

```
blacklist bluetooth
blacklist btusb
blacklist ath3k
```

You can enable it later using `modprobe <drivername`>

Comment: I will try it! Is there a way to remove the bluetooth apps that cause this problem?

Comment: The problem is not with any particular application but with the handling of the Atheros Bluetooth chipset driver `ath3k` by the Linux Kernel. Newer kernel releases have fixed this problem.

Comment: First command fails: `bash: cd: /usr/lib/modules/3.13.0-43-generic/kernel/drivers/bluetooth/: No such file or directory`.

Comment: The solution was for Arch Linux. I have modified the commands to work with Ubuntu. Let me know if this works.

Comment: Tried that using `sudo -i`, but the error still appears.

Comment: `E: Unable to locate package firmware-atheros` which is the most recent stable kernel that works fine with Ubuntu 14.04? Also, I want to get updates too.

Comment: Try the blacklist method which I have added to the answer.

Comment: Worked perfectly after restart on Ubuntu 14.04, linux kernel 3.13.0-43-generic!

Comment: Update: Bluetooth stopped working again! any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same errors on my machine too and finally found a fix.  Blacklist the ath3k module `echo "blacklist ath3k" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/ath3k.conf`
and then `gksudo gedit /etc/rc.local` and add `modprobe ath3k` above the exit 0 line, save, exit and reboot

Firmware for the atheros bluetooth is part of linux-firmware `sudo apt-get install linux-firmware`

After install it should be located in /lib/firmware/ar3k